# persistant error "E676: No matching autocommands for acwrite buffer"

Tags: autocmd

I had a file called **a.txt** open in vim. I mashed some keys (I really don't know which) but when I tried to save the file `:w`
I got the above error. Same when I tried to quit the file. Finally, I forced quit with `:q!`
Then I deleted the file from my computer.

Here is what surprised me: When I created a new file with the name **a.txt**, I could not save it because I got the same error. There is no problem with any other file name I decide to choose. Obviously, this is not a huge problem, but I'm curious. I assume that whatever I did has been saved in some vim config file and associated with the name **a.txt**.
I opened the .viminfo file and deleted all lines associated with a.txt but the error persists.
Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: Error message (`:h E676`) indicates that your buffer is supposed to be written by user-supplied auto-commands only (`setl bt=acwrite`). How that could even happen, it's upon you and your broken config. See questions on this site about "debugging my vimrc" or just remove your config and use the defaults.

Comment: FYI: I was using terminal-buffer(opening terminal inside neovim) and was trying to run `:wqa` and this error happen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did that fixed it. I went in to ~/.vim/view and found the file for a.txt ('~=+a.txt=') and simply deleted it.
Everything is fine now.

Inside that file a config setting called:

```
setlocal buftype=
```

got set to

```
setlocal buftype=autocmd
```

Comment: Indeed, another reason I’ve recommended not automatically saving and restoring views all the time

Comment: `setlocal buftype=acwrite` ?